# Active Admin Normal Text Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm trying to bring a custom view to an active admins page.

But thing is whenever I try to put a text area field it automatically produces a custom text area field where I can set font and all, something like word editor as shown in picture.

[image]

Is there a way I can prevent this and get normal text editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. TinyMCE lets you specify a html class that prevents it from activating. Text fields with that class will not get transformed into the editor.

[http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:editor_deselector](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x%3aeditor_deselector)

Where you initialize TinyMCE, add these options:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    //your init code
    editor_deselector: 'selector', //replace this with the HTML class of your choice
    //more of your init code
  });
```

Any text area that has the specified class will not get transformed into an editor.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in opposite way. Like passing the class of the textareas for which that style should not render.
Now it is in the opposite way. This is because my app is huge and i want the customized editor more and this normal editor for 1 or 2 times. thats why

Comment: There is an opposite version of the `editor_selector` called `editor_deselector`. I'll edit my answer.